# Is client implementation for HTTP basic and digest authentication the same?

Tags: http, apache-httpclient-4.x, http-authentication, basic-authentication, http-digest

According to Apache's guide to [HTTP authentication](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/authentication.html). Both basic and digest authentication requires a UsernamePasswordCredentials instance.

My question is can I use the same client implementation for server authentication for both basic and digest following this [example](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/examples/BasicAuthenticationExample.java?view=markup)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can and you should. HttpClient is capable of employing different auth schemes in the course of a single request execution (for instance using Basic to authenticate with the proxy and NTLM to authenticate with the origin server)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @oleg. Can you tell me if you know good examples of multiple authentication for HttpClient 4.5x. All of examples I found are using deprecated classes and I am stuck in 401 unauthorized state. Regards.

Comment: What is wrong with these? http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/examples.html